# What does "exit" mean when used in investment?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I read some blogs, there are something like "I invested 20 startups, among which 10 exit".

What does exit mean? Means the startup failed? broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that they sold the equity (shares) in which they had invested, generally with a profit.

It is a common expression in finance and refers to what is generally referred to as "***[the exit strategy](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/exitstrategy.asp)***".

> - The method by which a venture capitalist or business owner intends to get out of an investment that he or she has made in the past. In other words, the exit strategy is a way of "cashing out" an investment. Examples include an initial public offering (IPO) or being bought out by a larger player in the industry. Also referred to as a "harvest strategy" or "liquidity event".

Investopedia

In your example, the investor is saying that they invested in 20 start-ups and that they sold the shares of 10 of them.

Comment: You mean people who invested startup sold the equity of the startup company, and they made money?

Comment: Yes, they may also sell at a loss if the investment was not that profitable.